# recording user's post like time

Tags: python, django, django-models, time, django-views

I am building a simple BlogApp and I am trying to `record user like post time`.
I have created a field named `like_time` But the problem is when `user_1` like the post than the time is recorded But when `user_2` like than it resets the `user_1` time, But i am trying to store different like time of different of different users.

models.py

```
class BlogPost(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    title = models.CharField(max_length-300)
    likes = models.ManyToManyField(User, related_name='likes')
    body = models.CharField(max_length=300)
    like_time = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
```

views.py

```
def blog_post_like(request, blogpost_id):
    post = get_object_or_404(BlogPost, pk=blogpost_id)

    if request.user not in post.likes.all():
        post.likes.add(request.user)
        post.like_time = timezone.now()
        post.save()
        return JsonResponse({'disp':'success'})
```

**The Problem :-**

It is resetting for every user on same post, But I am trying to store different like time for different users, like :-

```
user_1 - liked time - 40 seconds ago

user_2 - liked_time - 30 seconds ago
```

Any help would be much Appreciated .Thank You

Answer (score 0):

Instead of declaring the relationship between Likes and BlogPost, try to declare it into the Like model.

```
class Like(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    blogPost = models.ForeignKey(BlogPost, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    like_time = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
```

Comment: I did it once but there was another problem. *Can't i make another model for just storing time ?*

Comment: What was the problem that time?

Comment: It was showing like button multiple times, so i dropped that idea.

Comment: But this is a front-end problem and not a back-end.

Comment: So that's why i didn't ask  about in this question, I was a past problem, and as i said i never mentioned in this question

Comment: Can you post the model of the Like please?